# Android: Table Layout alignment problem

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have a LinearLayout, inside there is a TableLayout
1st row, contains a center aligned image;
2nd/3rd/... rows, contains two EditText fields.
I need all the rows from 2nd row should be left aligned ("Name": "Value").

But in my case, "Name" part is left aligned, that is ok, but the "Value" part is starting from above row's image's right edge..

Can anybody help to fix this.

Here is my layout:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:minWidth="310dp" android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_height="1dip" />

            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <!--  Details tab -->

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabContentDetails"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" android:stretchColumns="0"
                        android:background="@drawable/transparent_border_shape">
                        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"                              
                            android:gravity="center">
                                <ImageView android:id="@+id/update_details_img"
                                    android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="200dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/q_silhouette" android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:gravity="center">
                                </ImageView>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/csTitle"
                                    android:padding="3dip" android:textSize="7pt"
                                    android:textColor="@color/Black"  />
                            </TableRow>                         
                            <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">                               
                                <TextView android:text="Date ed:" android:padding="3dip"
                                    android:textColor="@color/registration_fields_title"
                                    android:textSize="7pt" />
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/csDated"
                                    android:padding="3dip" android:textSize="7pt"
                                    android:textColor="@color/Black"  />                                
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
                                <TextView android:text="Posted By:" android:padding="3dip"
                                    android:textColor="@color/registration_fields_title"
                                    android:textSize="7pt" />
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/csPostedBy"
                                    android:padding="3dip" android:textSize="7pt"
                                    android:textColor="@color/Black"  />
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
                                <TextView android:text="Description:" android:padding="3dip"
                                    android:textColor="@color/registration_fields_title"
                                    android:textSize="7pt" />
                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/csDescription" android:textColor="@color/Black"
                                    android:paddingTop="2dp" android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                                    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                                    android:minWidth="290dp" android:minHeight="90dp" android:isScrollContainer="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/transparent_border_shape">

                                </TextView>
                            </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--  Comments tab -->

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabContentComments"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in adavance
- Venkat

Comment: Can you post the xml you're using now - a simple picture of what you're trying to achieve would also be helpful to people answering, otherwise a more complete description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `gravity` of table layout to center and make sure the width is fill_parent. also use android:stretchColumns="field"

Comment: Hi Rohit, by placing table layout's width to "fill_parent"; all the rows, getting left aligned; but i need the first row (image) as center aligned. when i use "wrap_content", i'm getting the layout as explained my question. In both cases, i didnt find any change by using android:stretchColumns="field" attribute...

Comment: its due to the uneven elements in your TableRow tag. In tablelayout for the tablerow tags, each tablerow should have equal count of elements. In case if you dont want to show an element in a row, just set its visibility to invisible.

Comment: means, should I need to add a dummy invisible <TextView> in each row?

Comment: exactly which is just mean to align the table. If you dont want to show that just set its visibility to invisible not gone.